# Couchbase with C#, "Bucket.Result" gives "Fatal" and "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <" most of time

Tags: c#, couchbase

I am new in Couchbase and want to execute a Group By query on database. I have created an MVC application using C#.NET. Below is the code snippet:

```
var config = new ClientConfiguration
{
    Servers = new List<Uri>
  {
       new Uri("http://172.18.109.151:8091/pools"),
       new Uri("http://172.18.109.81:8091/pools"),
       new Uri("http://172.18.109.46:8091/pools"),
       new Uri("http://172.18.109.60:8091/pools"),
       new Uri("http://172.18.109.80:8091/pools")
  },
    UseSsl = false,
    DefaultOperationLifespan = 8100000,
    BucketConfigs = new Dictionary<string, BucketConfiguration>
                  {
                    {"NLA-testing", new BucketConfiguration
                    {
                      BucketName = "NLA-testing",
                      UseSsl = false,
                      Password = "",
                      DefaultOperationLifespan = uint.MaxValue,
                      PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration
                      {
                        MaxSize = 10,
                        MinSize = 5,
                        SendTimeout = int.MaxValue, // this value wa
                      }
                    }}}
};

using (Cluster cls = new Cluster(config))
{
    using (var buc = cls.OpenBucket("NLA-testing"))
    {
        string AggQuery = "SELECT Status.StatusCode, Status.Detail, Status.Meaning, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `NLA-testing` where  (Status.StatusCode is not missing and Status.Detail is not missing and Status.Meaning is not missing)GROUP BY Status.StatusCode, Status.Detail, Status.Meaning";
        var AggResult = buc.Query<dynamic>(AggQuery);
        foreach (var row in AggResult.Rows)
        {
            if (row["StatusCode"] != null)
                datalist.Add(new StatusCount(Convert.ToInt32(row["StatusCode"]), Convert.ToInt32(row["count"]), row["Meaning"].ToString(), row["Detail"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Below line creates error. "QueryResult.Status" gives "Fatal" and Exception gives "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0." message.

> var AggResult = buc.Query(AggQuery);

More information is shown in below image:

[AggResult information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9I1Y.jpg)

I don't know why it is happening. Is my configuration missing anything or I am using wrong way to execute a query? If I run the code for multiple times then "QueryResult.Status" gives "Success" once in 10 runs.

Can you please help me to solve it out?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run the query not in a dev environment, let's say cbq or cbq ui and see if you can get the result?
What version are you using? (couchbase/sdk/etc)

Comment: Yes, I have tried from cbq also and it works fine. The discussion is going on at couchbase forum. Till now it looks like proxy problem. Please refer the link  https://forums.couchbase.com/t/why-c-net-query-gives-fatal-status-most-of-the-time/8547?u=ghodasarac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy created a problem and now it's solved.

I have listed 5 IP addresses in Servers list (in ClientConfiguration). The application is running from 172.18.109.151 only, which is having proxy settings. Hence, when

> var AggResult = buc.Query(AggQuery);

statement executes, it makes a request to a query service on any of above 5 list using http://172.18.109.XXX:8093/query (here XXX is any of 151,81,46,60,80). Hence it gives error "Invalid Request" [HTTP/1.0 417 Expectation Failed whose content type is "text/html"].

I removed proxy from the PC executing query and it's working fine.
More discussion can be found on: [Why C#.net query gives "FATAL" status most of the time? (forum.couchbase.com)](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/why-c-net-query-gives-fatal-status-most-of-the-time/8547?u=ghodasarac)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase is configured use http 80 port to query views and the proxy responds with an authentication error.
To solve this you need to configure .NET not to use default proxy in this case. This is done in the relevant config files:

Added the following to my Projects App.config has resolved the issue for me:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```